maven dependency not found with Java FX 19 on Eclipse 2024-06 but not earlier
I have the following issue with Eclipse 2024-06: A project that references
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Java FX -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

in its pom.xml shows the error org.openfx:javafx-base:jar:${javafx.platform}:19 was not found in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2.
This error is not there in earlier versions of Eclipse (e.g., Eclipse 2024-03).
How can I work on Java 11/17 Projects that reference JavaFX 11/19 in the latest version of Eclipse?
Notes:

The error also exists if you have a project that references a dependency that references JavaFX. So upgrading JavaFX is not (always) an option, if you need to work with some given dependency.

The error also comes up if you set the <version> to 22, but it is gone if you set the <version> to `23-ea+22

The property ${javafx.platform} is not defined in the projects pom.xml but Eclipse shows that the property is defined with Default Value: mac.



Why not update to latest?  23-ea+22

The error also exists if you reference an artifact that has javafx 19 in its dependency. I can update my project, but not those of others. The error also exists with 22, but not with 23-ea+22. Nevertheless, it appears to be a bug in Eclipse, right?

What is ${javafx.platform} supposed to be a placeholder for, and how is the actual value defined?

The placeholder should be - afaik - "win", "linux" or "mac". It is not define as a property in the pom. It is somehow inferred. Also: It appears only in the error message. Download of Eclipse and import of the project works out-of-the-box with 2024-03 and has the error with 2024-06

Java’s long-term support versions are 8, 11, 17, and 21. Java 19 is end-of-life. As I recall, JavaFX follows the same lifecycle policies.

Another approach is to use a JDK that comes bundled with the JavaFX libraries, implemented as OpenJFX. At least two JDK vendors offer a bundle: Azul Systems and BellSoft.

@BasilBourque The problem is also there if I configure the project to be Java 17 with JavaFX 17. - But apart from that: I would assume that Eclipse should allow working on legacy projects, if configured as such. - For the other comment: how would you specify this in a Maven pom file? - I have no problem working in Eclipse 2024-03, it is just that I have users that complain that the project does not work in Eclipse 2024-06, although the project builds flawless on the command line.

To clarify… (a) The June 12th release of the Eclipse IDE 2024-06 - 4.32 requires Java 21. (b) OpenJFX (the implementation of JavaFX) version 22 requires Java 17+. So you should be able to use Java 22 to build and run a project with Java 17 as the level for source & target (or their replacement, release) elements in the POM file. (c) I tried doing this by creating a new project in IntelliJ using its nifty JavaFX template for new projects, then import into Eclipse. Unfortunately, I could not for the life of me figure out how to build and run the project in Eclipse IDE.

@BasilBourque Thank you. Yes. Eclipse 2024-06 requires Java 21+ to run. I ran it under JDK 22. - The question is about the development target. You can develop for a JDK 17 (even 11, or 8) target (see Settings -> Java -> Compiler and  Settings -> Java -> Installed JRE (I got this error for Eclipse running under Java 22 developing for a Java 17 Target).

@ChristianFries I do not know if this helps you or not, but I posted a copy of the Maven POM file created by the JavaFX project template in IntelliJ. See this Answer of mine. Changing the source & target elements to 17 works, the project builds & runs in IntelliJ 2024.2 Beta. In theory, this should work in Eclipse IDE as well.

I think this might be the same as Maven project fails to resolve JavaFX dependencies. At least for me, Eclipse 2024-06 seems to use that Maven version by default.

@dan1st Thank you. This is very useful. So Eclipse 2024-06 references Maven 3.9.7 and Maven has a bug...  make sense. I try to verify it.

Also it seems like IntelliJ has the same problem.

Aside from that, note that using a different Maven version in Preferences>Maven>Installations doesn't help because these aren't used for dependency resolution as noted at the bottom of that menu. However, you could try uninstalling m2e and installing an older m2e version in Eclipse.

This is a issue in Maven 3.9.7 which is also mentioned in this answer. It was addressed in Maven 3.9.8.
Apparently, the issue is due to profile IDs in the JavaFX artifacts:

In short, OpenJFX parent provides invalid POM since 2021. The crux is that parent POM uses conflicting Profile IDs, that simple Maven validation shows (as one can expect, fields having "ID" in their name are supposed to be, well, "identifiers"):

As Eclipse 2024-06 uses that Maven version as the embedded Maven version, you will get this error in that Eclipse version as well.
Option 1 (Recommended): update Eclipse
Eclipse 2024-09 normally comes with m2e 2.6.2 which bundles Maven 3.9.9 so if you update to that or later, you shouldn't get this issue any more.
To update Eclipse, select Help > Check for Updates and follow the dialog.

You can then check the Eclipse version via Help > About Eclipse IDE:

If this is 2024-09, you should be good:

You can also check the version of the m2e plugin which should be 2.6.2 or later by clicking on Installation Details and searching for m2e:

Option 2: update JavaFX
It seems like this problem was also handled on JavaFX' side with the latest versions.
So, one way to fix this is to update to a different JavaFX version like 21.0.4 or 22.0.2 (I would avoid ones with -ea in the version name if possible as these are early access builds but you can also go with 23-ea+22 as you already noticed).
As you can see in the POM of JavaFX 21.0.3 for example, there are multiple profiles with the same <id>. This is not the case for JavaFX 21.0.4 which uses different profile ids
Option 3 (NOT RECOMMENDED): update the M2Eclipse plugin
If you can't update to Eclipse 2024-09 and also don't want to update JavaFX, you could update m2e to version 2.6.2 or later (which is currently a snapshot meaning it might have other bugs!) without updating all of Eclipse.
To do this, you need to add the snapshot update site for m2e 2.6.2 (in principle, you could also use https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/snapshots/latest/ if you also want future m2e snapshots but I wouldn't recommend that unless you know what you are doing and are ok with encountering some bugs because of that).
You can do so from the Install New Software dialog:

Click the Add button and add a new repository with the URL https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/snapshots/2.6.2/:

Select that repository as well as M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse, click Next and install it:

This should change the embedded Maven version to 3.9.8 as you can see in Window>Preferences>Maven>Installations:

